# Adding intermediate certificate to openssl_pkcs7_sign

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I am using this code to sign a file :

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign($in,$out,
     cert.crt,
     cert.key,
     array(),
     PKCS7_NOATTR
);
```

However it still appears as not verified when it is opened.

On the contrary, this openssl command works fine:

```
openssl smime -sign -in in -out out -signer cert.crt -inkey cert.key -certfile ca-bundle -outform der -nodetach
```

Why is the PHP code not working ?

Answer (score 3):

OK,

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign($in,$out,
     cert.crt,
     cert.key,
     array(),
     PKCS7_NOATTR,
     "/real/path/of/ca/intermeidate/cert/file.pem"
        );
```

Did the trick. The last $extracerts arg uses real path instead of file://

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just saved me a significant headache

Comment: @Reviewers, I don't think the edit I suggested for that post was "intended to address the author of the post". I think it fully "makes sense as an edit", because it significantly improves the quality of the answer. Can you please expand on your rejection ?